# responsive image bootstrap5.2 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make responsive the images that are in this tags: img src="images/5902216.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;" but it doesn't work for some reason. I am using bootstrap 5.2.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1aca141b14.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom">
       <div class="container">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
               <img src="logo.png" alt="Avatar Logo" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill">
           </a>

           <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
               aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>

           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
               <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">Home</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Services</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Compétences</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Portfolio</a>
                   </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">À Propos</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Contact</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </nav>


   <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
       <div class="carousel-inner">
           <div class="carousel-item active">
               <img src="images/114-1144561_copyright-free-images-on-desk-with-laptop-and.jpg" class="d-block w-100"
                   style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
               <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                   <h5>Portfolio</h5>
                   <p>Développeur Web Indépendant</p>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item">
               <img src="images/269-2698560_high-resolution-laptop-desktop-wallpaper-hd.jpg" class="d-block w-100"
                   style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
               <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                   <h5 class="text-center">Création de sites web</h5>
                   <p class="text-center">Site vitrine, e-commerce, forum et autres</p>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item">
               <img src="images/10705380.jpg" class="d-block w-100" style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
               <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                   <h5 class="text-center">Web design, conception graphiques</h5>
                   <p class="text-center">Logos, plaquettes publicitaire, cartes de visites,
                       newsletters</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
           <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
       </button>
       <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
           <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
       </button>
   </div>
   <section class="caseservices" style="padding: 4%;">
       <div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading1">
           <h1>MES SERVICES</h1>
           <h3>Des prestations adaptées à vos besoins</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading2">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col">
                   <div class="row align-items-center">
                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-end">Gestion de projets web</h5>
                           <p class="text-end">Site vitrine, corporate, évènementiel, e-commerce, intranet, application
                               mobile.
                           </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-2">
                           <i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fa-2xl"></i>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-end">Intégration Web</h5>
                           <p class="text-end">Des intégrations (X)HTML / CSS respectueuses des standards du Web.</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-2">
                           <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-2xl"></i>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-end">Développements spécifiques</h5>
                           <p class="text-end">Des outils adaptés à votre coeur de métier,
                               applications & solutions personnalisées.</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-2">
                           <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench fa-2xl"></i>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-end">Référencement naturel</h5>
                           <p class="text-end">Affichage sémantique des informations,
                               des pages propres pour un référencement optimal.</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-2">

                           <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/5902216.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col">
                   <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
               </div>
               <div class="col">
                   <div class="row align-items-center">
                       <div class="col-2">

                           <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img
                                   src="images/kisspng-icon-design-web-development-responsive-web-design-black-brush-5afd4d493dd9d2.7237427015265498332534.png"
                                   alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-start">Conception graphique & Webdesign</h5>
                           <p class="text-start">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires,
                               cartes de visite, newsletters...</p>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-2">

                           <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/3938579.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>

                       </div>
                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-start">Dynamisme des pages</h5>
                           <p class="text-start">Des animations de contenu non intrusives
                               pour embellir votre projet.</p>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-2">

                           <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/2739572-200.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-start">Interface d'administration</h5>
                           <p class="text-start">Outils spécifiques au bon fonctionnement
                               de votre entreprise.</p>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-2">

                           <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/1027666.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-10">
                           <h5 class="text-start">Responsive design</h5>
                           <p class="text-start">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application mobile.</p>
                       </div>


                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>

           <p>Compatible Mobile, Tablettes & P.C</p>
           <h3>Développement Web Responsive</h3>
       </div>
   </section>

   <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 4%;" href="scrollspyHeading3">
       <h1>MES COMPÉTENCES</h1>
       <h3>Des compétences à votre service</h3>
       <div class="container text-center">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col text-start">
                   <h4>Domaines de compétences</h4>
                   <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i> Gestion de projets web </h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">Site vitrine, corporate, évènementiel, e-commerce, intranet,
                       application
                       mobile.</p>

                   <h6> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Conception graphique &
                       Webdesign </h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires, cartes de visite,
                       newsletters...</p>

                   <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Applications spécifiques et
                       Interface d'administration</h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">PHP - MySQL - AJAX / ASP.NET - C# - SQL</p>

                   <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Mise en place / Modification
                       / Gestion de CMS</h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">Wordpress, Joomla, Prestashop, phpBB, IPBoard</p>

                   <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Intégration (X)HTML / CSS
                   </h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">Codage à la main respectueux des standards du Web</p>

                   <h6> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Dynamise des pages par
                       JavaScript / AJAX </h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, Scriptaculous</p>

                   <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Validation W3C, WAI &
                       référencement naturel SEO</h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;"> Accessibilité & ergonomie des pages web </p>

                   <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i> Conception multi-plateformes
                   </h6>
                   <p style="font-style: italic;">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application mobile</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col">
                   <h1>Compétences en développement</h1>
                   <div class="skills-bar">
                       <div class="bar">
                           <div class="info">
                               <span>HTML/CSS</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="progress-line html"><span></span></div>
                       </div>


                       <div class="bar">
                           <div class="info">
                               <span>JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="progress-line javascript"><span></span></div>
                       </div>


                       <div class="bar">
                           <div class="info">
                               <span>PHP</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="progress-line php"><span></span></div>
                       </div>


                       <div class="bar">
                           <div class="info">
                               <span>laravel</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="progress-line python"><span></span></div>
                       </div>


                       <div class="bar">
                           <div class="info">
                               <span>MYSQL</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="progress-line mysql"><span></span></div>
                       </div>

                   </div>
               </div>

               <h1 class="text-center">Une idée ? Un projet ? N'hésitez pas à demander un devis ! [GRATUIT]</h1>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 4%;" href="scrollspyHeading4">
       <h1>MES PROJETS</h1>
       <h4>Une partie des projets sur lesquels j'ai travaillé</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 4%;" href="scrollspyHeading6">
       <h1>À PROPOS</h1>
       <h4>Je suis développeur web freelance et j'aime ça !</h4>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col">
               <h4 class="text-start">Un développeur web passionné !</h4>
               <p class="text-start">Ma passion pour le développement web commence en 2003 et m'a demandé un changement
                   radical de cursus
                   afin de pouvoir pleinement l'exploiter.</br> </br>

                   Dès lors, je mis tout en oeuvre pour percer dans cette voie, tout en prenant du plaisir sur les
                   divers projets développés.</br> </br>

                   En Mai 2009, je décide de devenir développeur web indépendant après plusieurs postes en tant que
                   développeur web « full-stack » réussis, qui me conforteront dans cette idée afin de toucher un plus
                   large panel de domaines d'activités, voir du pays et conquérir le monde !</p>
           </div>

           <div class="col">
               <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
           </div>

           <div class="col">

               <h4 class="text-start">Expérience en développement</h4>

               <p class="text-start"> Mon expérience acquise au fil des projets me permet de mieux comprendre les
                   attentes d'un client
                   et de
                   répondre précisement au besoin demandé en fonction du domaine d'activité.</p>

               <p class="text-start">Du site vitrine au projet plus complexe, je vous propose une expertise et un
                   développement web qui
                   correspond à vos attentes & à vos besoins.</p>

               <h3 class="text-start">Un tarif adapté à votre projet</h3>

               <p class="text-start"> Travaillant régulièrement avec des PME, associations ou particuliers, je vous
                   propose des solutions
                   à
                   votre portée & adaptée à votre budget.</p>

           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading7" style="padding: 4%;">
       <h1>CONTACTEZ-MOI</h1>
       <h3 style="background-color: grey;padding: 1%;">Une idée ? Un projet ? N'hésitez pas à demander un devis !
           [GRATUIT]</h3>

       <div class="row align-items-center" style="padding: 3%;">
           <div class="col text-start">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col">
                       <div class="row">

                           <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                               <i class="material-icons align-items-center"><img src="images/img_288659.png" alt=""
                                       style="width: 50%;"></i>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-10"
                               style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3px;  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                               <h6>ADRESSE</h6>
                               <p>45, allée des Grives 83390 Cuers</p>
                           </div>


                           <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                               <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/free-phone-icon-14-thumb.png" alt=""
                                       style="width: 50%;"></i>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-10"
                               style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3px;  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                               <h6>Téléphone</h6>
                               <p>(+33) 6.15.42.10.45</p>
                           </div>


                           <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                               <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/Vector-Email-Symbol-PNG-Image.png" alt=""
                                       style="width: 50%;"></i>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-10" style="padding-top: 3%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                               <h6>E-mail</h6>
                               <p>contact@mcrevoulin.com</p>
                           </div>


                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
               <iframe
                   src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d84484.16954505828!2d7.69203969606045!3d48.56905316140801!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4796c8495e18b2c1%3A0x971a483118e7241f!2sStra%C3%9Fburg%2C%20Frankreich!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1658941325979!5m2!1sde!2sde"
                   width="300" height="200" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
                   referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
               <!-- <iframe
                   src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d316530.06898113067!2d38.75890546037433!3d51.69843674434513!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x413b2f5ce874e813%3A0x48d94c0efba762bd!2sWoronesch%2C%20Oblast%20Woronesch%2C%20Russland!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1658941426253!5m2!1sde!2sde"
                   width="300" height="200" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
                   referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe> -->
           </div>
           <div class="col">
               Column
           </div>
       </div>

   </div>


   <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

when I shrink the screen to put the images in this shrink tag like on a phone and we don't see them. In this link you can see result of my code https://testportfolio111.000webhostapp.com/ I have add img-fluid to seo picture but this doesn't work. How can i do for when screen are smallest picture are responsive?

Answer (score 0):

You have Forgot to add bootstrap class for responsive image.
Add class ".img-fluid" to your image tag.

```
          <img class="img-fluid" src=".." />
```